AWS Amplify Gen 2 - Send email using AWS SES in Gen 2
I'm working on a Nuxt 3 application that uses AWS Amplify Hosting (Gen 2), and I want to send emails via AWS SES using a Lambda function. I have created the following Lambda function:
import type { Schema } from "../../data/resource";
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";

const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: "af-south-1" });

export const handler: Schema["sendEmail"]["functionHandler"] = async (event) => {
  const recipient = "testemail@gmail.com";
  const subject = "Subject";
  const body = "Body";

  const command = new SendEmailCommand({
    Source: "testemail@gmail.com",
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [recipient],
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: { Data: body },
      },
      Subject: { Data: subject },
    },
  });

  try {
    const result = await sesClient.send(command);
    console.log(`Email sent to ${recipient}: ${result.MessageId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error sending email to ${recipient}: ${error}`);
    throw new Error(`Failed to send email to ${recipient}`, { cause: error });
  }

  return `Hello, ${event.name}!`;
};

In my front end I am triggering the lamda as follow:
import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/api";
import type { Schema } from "~/amplify/data/resource";

const client = generateClient<Schema>();
const response = await client.queries.sendEmail({
  name: "Amplify",
});

I do get error when I trigger this lamda "Not Authorized to access sendEmail on type Query"
this is my backend resource setup
import { type ClientSchema, a, defineData } from '@aws-amplify/backend';
import { sendEmail } from '../functions/send-email/resource';

const schema = a.schema({

  sendEmail: a
    .query()
    .arguments({
      name: a.string(),
    })
    .returns(a.string())
    .authorization((allow) => [allow.guest() ,allow.authenticated()])
    .handler(a.handler.function(sendEmail)),

  Todo: a
    .model({
      content: a.string(),
    })
    .authorization((allow) => [allow.publicApiKey(), allow.guest() ,allow.authenticated()]),
});

export type Schema = ClientSchema<typeof schema>;

export const data = defineData({
  schema,
  authorizationModes: {
    defaultAuthorizationMode: 'apiKey',
    apiKeyAuthorizationMode: { expiresInDays: 30 }
  }
});

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Specifically, I’d like to know:

Is this the best way to send emails via SES, or would creating a
custom class provide a better solution?
How can I securely trigger
the email from the frontend application?
What permissions are required to ensure the Lambda function can send emails successfully?

I’ve already verified my email address in the SES af-south-1 region.
Thanks in advance for your help!

On Frontend, You will need to specify authMode.
import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/api";
import type { Schema } from "~/amplify/data/resource";

const client = generateClient<Schema>();
const response = await client.queries.sendEmail({
  name: "Amplify",
},{
    authMode: "userPool"
});


Update
I have added the following policies to my amplify/backend.ts
const backend = defineBackend({
   auth,
   data,
   sendEmail
});

   backend.sendEmail.resources.lambda.addToRolePolicy(
     new PolicyStatement({
     actions: ['ses:SendEmail', 'ses:SendRawEmail'],
     resources: ['*']
   })
)

This is working now.
